# PHPmailer sends duplicates if page refreshed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've got this problem since two months ago, and still strugling with it.
I'm using PHPMailer for my mailinglist program. And I have a cron job which runs in certain times. However, there is a problem with the emails.

I use PHPMailer in a loop where I send to all of the mailinglist members. The codes look like this:

```
<?php
require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SingleTo = true;
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Subject = "Our news";
$r_receivers = array("John"=>"john@mail.com","Mary"=>"mary@mail.com","Rob"=>"rob@mail.com");

foreach($r_receivers as $name=>$email){
    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@oursite.com', "Oursite");
    $mail->MsgHTML($sendContent);
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
        $sendContent = "<p>E-mail body</p>";
    if($mail->Send())
        echo "Sent to: ".$email."<br/>";
    else
        echo "Not sent to: ".$email.", reason: ".$mail->ErrorInfo."<br/>";
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
}?>
```

when I call this codes with ajax, it works perfect. However, if I execute this codes in a browser or refresh it or call it with cron job, it sends me duplicates.

Can someone explain me why is it going wrong when I open it with browser/refresh? Why I got different result by calling it with ajax and calling it from browser?

Comment: When you reload the web page, you execute a new request. So the code is executed again and the mail will be sent out. Think about checking time and ip from the previous send action, that it won't be executed until some time passed.

Comment: Do you mean that when you load this in your browser, you get more than one email sent?

Comment: Yes, when I load this file in a browser, I receives more than one emails.

Comment: Can you add a trace code (var_dump($mail)) within the loop to see whether the loop is executed twice or its comes through the phpmailer?

Comment: The result says that I only sent once, but I got 2 emails in my inbox.

Comment: 3 emails seems logical, given that you are looping through 3 elements in $r_receivers. Do you mean it sends 3 emails to each recipient address?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an open issue related to this: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/issues/detail?id=31. You may want to bring your copy of PHPMailer up to the latest version and try again. The issue status is "fixed", though it appears from the comments in the issue ticket that the problem may still exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SingleTo, which is discouraged. According to the authors of the PHPMailer library, SingleTo is planned to be deprecated in the release of PHPMailer 6.0, and removed in 7.0. The authors have explained that it's better to control sending to multiple recipients at a higher level, since PHPMailer isn't a mailing list sender. They tell that the use of the PHP mail() function needs to be discouraged also, because it's extremely difficult to use safely; SMTP is faster, safer, and gives more control and feedback. And since SMTP is incompatible with SingleTo, the authors of PHPMailer will remove SingleTo, not SMTP.